# How to get row and column number of cell that matches a given value in data.frame or distance matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe

When I have a distance matrix (or a data frame based on a  matrix), how do I get the row and column that corresponds to a given value?

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(11:20), y= c(12:21))
dst <- dist(df)
```

Output:

```
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
2   1.414214                                                                                
3   2.828427  1.414214                                                                      
4   4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                                            
5   5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                                  
6   7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                                        
7   8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                              
8   9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214                    
9  11.313708  9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214          
10 12.727922 11.313708  9.899495  8.485281  7.071068  5.656854  4.242641  2.828427  1.414214
```

Now I want to input e.g. 11.313708 and get as output (9, 1)

Comment: Be aware of this when comparing floating point values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We convert to a matrix and get the index with `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` (assuming that it is what you wanted).

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(dst)
 which(m1==val, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Otherwise, we can use the regular subsetting by row, column if we already know the index of the value.  As @nicola mentioned in the comments, there is a chance for floating point issues.  To avoid that may be `round` it and then do the comparison. i.e.

```
 which(round(m1, 3)== 11.314, arr.ind=TRUE)
 #    row col
 #9    9   1
 #10  10   2
 #1    1   9
 #2    2  10
```

Comment: I'd warn about  floating point issues. For instance, `which(m1==11.313708, arr.ind=TRUE)` won't produce any result and don't know if they are aware of this.

Comment: With this I only get `row col`

Comment: @Azrael Read the link I provided as a comment to your question. Floating point comparisons should be avoided. Furthermore, keep in mind that when R print objects, it rounds the values; so the `m1[9,1]` is not actually `11.313708`, but something close to it.